# MSAL with angular fails to authenticate - fails while attempting to discover the instance

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, msal.js

While using SSO to sign on Azure using MSAL with Angular, I get redirected this URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common//discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/{organization}.onmicrosoft.com/{policyName}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common//discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/%7Borganization%7D.onmicrosoft.com/%7BpolicyName%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) endpoint.

... and the response is - `400 bad request error` or an `invalid_request` (in the xhr)

A curl comes back with this error:
`"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS50050: The request is malformed: invalid format for 'authorization_endpoint'`

Why would this happen for new users?

**update:**

```
MsalModule.forRoot(
      {
        auth: {
          ...
          validateAuthority: false,
          ...
        },
...
```

setting `validateAuthority: false` resolved this issue for now.
However, setting `validateAuthority` should not cause problems - this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AD, try to change your `authorization_endpoint` to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Policy name is always used for Azure AD B2C, format like: `https://{your-B2C-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/{organization}.onmicrosoft.com/{policyName}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.

Comment: thanks for your comment - but the authorization_endpoint is as expected.